# Not able to connect clickhouse ODBC from Tableau Server

Tags: odbc, tableau-api, clickhouse

I am trying to connect clickhouse from Tableau Server

To connect Tableau we installed clickhouse ODBC on Tableau Server Below are the odbc.ini & odbcinst.ini
Eg: Clickhouse is on 192.168.0.1
Eg: Tableau is on 192.168.0.2''

odbcinst.ini

```
> [ODBC Drivers] ClickHouse ODBC Driver (ANSI)    = Installed ClickHouse
> ODBC Driver (Unicode) = Installed
> 
> [ClickHouse ODBC Driver (ANSI)] Description = ODBC Driver (ANSI) for
> ClickHouse Driver      =
> /root/clickhouse-odbc/build/driver/libclickhouseodbc.so Setup       =
> /root/clickhouse-odbc/build/driver/libclickhouseodbc.so UsageCount  =
> 1
> 
> [ClickHouse ODBC Driver (Unicode)] Description = ODBC Driver (Unicode)
> for ClickHouse Driver      =
> /root/clickhouse-odbc/build/driver/libclickhouseodbc.so Setup       =
> /root/clickhouse-odbc/build/driver/libclickhouseodbc.so UsageCount  =
> 1 [ODBC] Trace=yes TraceFile= /tmp/clickhouse-odbc.log 
> 
> odbc.ini
> 
> [ODBC Data Sources] ClickHouse DSN (ANSI)    = ClickHouse ODBC Driver
> (ANSI) ClickHouse DSN (Unicode) = ClickHouse ODBC Driver (Unicode)
> 
> [ClickHouse DSN (ANSI)] Driver      = ClickHouse ODBC Driver (ANSI)
> Description = DSN (localhost) for ClickHouse ODBC Driver (ANSI)
> 
> ### New all-in one way to specify connection with [optional] settings:
> #Url = http://default@192.168.0.1:8123/query?database=default&max_result_bytes=4000000&buffer_size=3000000
> 
> #Url = http://192.168.0.1:8123
> 
> ### Old way: Server = 192.168.0.1 Database = default UID = default
> #PWD = password Port = 8123 Proto = http
> 
> DriverLog = yes DriverLogFile = /tmp/chlickhouse-odbc-driver.log
> 
> [ClickHouse DSN (Unicode)] Driver      = ClickHouse ODBC Driver
> (Unicode) Description = DSN (192.168.0.1) for ClickHouse ODBC Driver
> (Unicode)
```

We are able to do curl clickhouse from Tableau Server

But when we try to connect with Tableau we are getting error [image]

Comment: Look at these articles: https://altinity.com/blog/tag/tableau/.

Comment: did you solve it?